# Securing Self Hosted OWIN+Web API 2 with SSL

Tags: ssl, asp.net-web-api, fiddler, owin

I have configured my OWIN self hosted Web Api 2 app to start with https://... and attached a self-signed SSL cert to my application using netsh.  However, from Fiddler, I am still seeing clear-text through the HTTPS channel.

Does OWIN require special handling?

Thanks!

Comment: You had any luck on solving this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have Fiddler [decrypting SSL traffic](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS)?  Are you able to hit your app from a browser with the HTTPS URL?  Whatever the case, it's hard to tell if this is an OWIN issue without sample code (and optimally screenshots).

Comment: @ChrisSimmons I even could not start the https listening, could you help to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500596/enable-https-for-asp-net-web-api-2-self-host